# Getting deep learning tracker (GOTURN) to run opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, deep-learning, video-processing

I installed opencv-python and opencv-contrib-python:

```
~$ pip install opencv-python
~$ pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Both installations went smoothly, and I now have:

```
In [1]: import cv2    
In [2]: cv2.__version__
Out[2]: '3.4.0'
```

However, If I try to use the [`GOTURN`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d7/d4c/classcv_1_1TrackerGOTURN.html) tracker, I get the following error:

> ```
> cv2.error: /io/opencv/modules/dnn/src/caffe/caffe_io.cpp:1119:
> error: (-2) FAILED: fs.is_open(). Can't open "goturn.prototxt" in function ReadProtoFromTextFile
> ```

It seems like my installation is missing the model files [`goturn.prototxt`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_extra/blob/c4219d5eb3105ed8e634278fad312a1a8d2c182d/testdata/tracking/goturn.prototxt) and [`goturn.caffemodel`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_extra/blob/c4219d5eb3105ed8e634278fad312a1a8d2c182d/testdata/tracking/goturn.caffemodel.zip.004).

I can manually download the missing files from [git](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_extra/tree/c4219d5eb3105ed8e634278fad312a1a8d2c182d/testdata/tracking), but I don't know where to place them locally so opencv can read them.

Alternatively, is there a `pip install ...` or similar action that can automatically "install" these missing files in the right place for me?

Answer (score 4):

You need to download the goturn.prototxt file and goturn.caffemodel from the net and put it in same folder as your current working directory to run it.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I already figured this out. But I was hoping for a more general solution: I don't want to copy the GOTURN model for every project I develop that requires tracking... Is there a place (like the XML files of the VJ face detectors) that **all** my projects can read the GOTURN model from?

Comment: Hi, I download goturn.caffemodel.zip.001 to goturn.caffemodel.zip.004 models and use the `cv2.TrackerGOTURN_Params()` to set the models and prototxt path. Unfortunately, it does not work for me. Do you have any idea what is going wrong? @Shai

Comment: @MohammadrezaRiahi Sorry, but I haven't used this code for more than three years